# Generate unique ID upon creating a feature?

Tags: arcpy, global-id

Looking for a way to generate a unique Global ID within a feature set when a new feature is created.  For example, every time a sewer manhole is added, we need to generate a new unique Global ID that will remain with that feature throughout the life of the data set.  I've looked at having a script tool but not sure that is the best approach.  Ideally we want to automate this function so it runs in the background each time a new sewer feature is created.

We are using ArcGIS platform.

Answer (score 4):

Not that difficult overall, it all depends on your platform of choice and the events you have to hook into. [Python has some powerful API hooks](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) for creating a GUID/UUID that you can attach to the end of your DB insert or update method to update the record.
If you are using ESRI as your framework, the Global ID is a prebuilt option you can use as well.

Comment: +1 for the ESRI Global ID option. Very easy to use tool, however, the ID string is 36 characters, which might be more than you are wanting.

Comment: Thanks.  great info.  We are using ArcGIS platform.  Right now the data is in a personal gdb but we plan to convert to file eventually.  Need it to be automated when a feature is created.  Does the global ID allow me to say "MH0001" for a manhole or "SP0001" for sewer pipe?

Comment: No, its a system generated GUID. What you would want to do then is create a new unique ID based on your own logic; best case in ArcObjects since you can better index the ESRI features that way. You can create classes for each object type and before insert do a select on the existing feature IDs to see what the next logical one should be then insert with the appropriate value. If you go to a full database back end you can look at triggers which would be a smoother option for you in the long run.

Comment: awsome information +1